# UITableViewCell appearance not changing textLabel font

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, appearance

I have the following code in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function :

```
[[[UITableViewCell appearance] textLabel]setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"someFont" size:12]];
```

But for some reason this does not change the text in my table cells.

If in the table delegate function `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I add

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"someFont" size:12];
```

It does change the font to my desired one.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of iOS are you targeting?

Comment: are you using custom font?

Comment: @anonymous Yes I am using a custom font.

Comment: @Dan I am targeting IOS 7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting the `font` property of a `UITableViewCell` is not supported using the appearance proxy.

You can tell which properties are supported by looking in the header file for that class for `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`.

Take a look at `UITableViewCell.h` and you'll see that only `separatorInset` is supported (and `backgroundColor` as this is supported by its superclass, `UIView`):

`@property (nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets separatorInset NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR; // allows customization of the separator frame`

---

From the [`UIAppearance` protocol reference:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

> To support appearance customization, a class must conform to the `UIAppearanceContainer` protocol and relevant accessor methods must be marked with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`.

Comment: Why the down vote? This is the correct answer, but if you think it can be improved, please let me know how!

Comment: Thanks! But I'm looking now in the UITableViewCell.h and i can't see any UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR

Comment: Hmm. I pasted code copied directly from `UITableViewCell.h` into my answer… does that help you locate it?

Comment: It's not that the Font property isn't supported, but a UITableViewCell doesn't have a Font. I think you're looking for the Font property on the UILabel.